# Displaying tips/instruction when launching app for 1st time

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile

I am considering creating an introduction/instruction/tips for my android studio app - "how to use it, what this button does". When user for first time opens the app it should give some tips, for example: this button is used for navigating in map (or something like this). Half year ago I installed app (forgot the name :D) and the first screen activity went into gray shades and highlited only single options. After I passed a few steps of introduction into app started working as normal. Any ideas how to create something like this? I was searching in google but I have no clue how to name this functionality.

Pedro

Comment: use this awesome library https://github.com/ECLaboratorio/BubbleShowCase-Android. pass unique id it will show only one tips/instruction.

Comment: Lovely! Thank you very much :)